# SQL SERVER 2012, 10 Million Rows, Match Multiple Fields In Same Table To Get Results

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Have 10 million records in a temporary table called `#Temp`. The columns are

```
PrimaryKey, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELDS3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6, DateField
```

Where PrimaryKey in Numeric while all other fields are VarChar except DateField.

Now I want to get the duplicate records from this table in the format.

```
IsDuplicate, PrimaryKey1, PrimaryKey2, DateField1, DateField2
```

Currently, the following query is running but it's taking a very very long time to execute.

```
   With DATA
(SELECT d.FIELD1 AS key1, d.* FROM #TEMP d WHERE  d.FIELD1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT d.FIELD2 AS key1, d.* FROM #TEMP d WHERE  d.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT d.FIELD3 AS key1, d.* FROM #TEMP d WHERE  d.FIELD3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT d.FIELD4 AS key1, d.* FROM #TEMP d WHERE  d.FIELD4 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT d.FIELD5 AS key1, d.* FROM #TEMP d WHERE  d.FIELD5 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT distinct IsDuplicate, PK1, PK2, DATE1, DATE2
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN CASE WHEN T1.FIELD1 = T2.FIELD1 AND T1.FIELD1 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD1 != ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+CASE
WHEN T1.FIELD2 = T2.FIELD2 AND T1.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD2 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+CASE
WHEN T1.FIELD3 = T2.FIELD3 AND T1.FIELD3 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD3 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD4 = T2.FIELD4 AND T1.FIELD4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD5 = T2.FIELD5 AND T1.FIELD5 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD5 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD6 = T2.FIELD6 AND T1.FIELD6 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD6 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsDuplicate,
CASE
WHEN T1.FIELD1 = T2.FIELD1 AND T1.FIELD1 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD1 != ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD3 = T2.FIELD3 AND T1.FIELD3 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD3 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD4 = T2.FIELD4 AND T1.FIELD4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD5 = T2.FIELD5 AND T1.FIELD5 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD5 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN T1.FIELD6 = T2.FIELD6 AND T1.FIELD6 IS NOT NULL AND T1.FIELD6 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPotential, 
T1.PK AS PK1, T2.PK AS PK2, T1.Date AS DATE1, T2.Date AS DATE2
FROM Data T1
INNER JOIN Data T2 ON T1.key1 = T2.key1
) R where R.IsDuplicate = 1
OR R.IsPotential >= 3
```

Looking for an alternate way to get the desired result in an optimised way.

Thanks.

Comment: Indexes? Execution plan? It's impossible to help without the relevant information? If you have 10M rows though, why are you using a *temporary* table? Did you add any indexes to that table? Finally, what *is* the desired result? What does that query do? It looks like it's just trying to load everything?

Comment: @Alcapoon  Is it a mispelling error the absence of FIELD2 in the second group of CASE?

Comment: Is it possible to have values that occur more than two times? Your output format probably can't handle this situation well...

Comment: HI! Field names used in the above query are dummy ones...actual field name are like first name, last name, state, zip, email etc......The 10 Million rows are relevant fields loaded from actual physical tables into a temporary table for processing the desired result......

Comment: In your `CASE` statements you do `T1.FIELD2 = T2.FIELD2 AND T1.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL` but depending on `ANSI_NULLS` setting it normally isn't necessary to include the `T1.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL` because `NULL` isn't equal to anything, including another `NULL`: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/